# "Transform" a matrix into a matrix with full column rank

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Consider this matrix
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0  &|&  1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0   &|& 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0  &|&  1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   - & - & - & -  &|&  - & - & - & -\\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0  &|&  0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0  &|&  0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0  &|&  0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0  &|&  0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
   - & - & - & -  &|&  - & - & - & -\\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0  &|&  0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0  &|&  0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0  &|&  0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
- & - & - & -  &|&  - & - & - & -\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1  &|&  1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1  &|&  0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

This matrix has size $12\times 8$ and it has rank $6$.

I want to find **all** the **pairs** of columns of $A$ that, once deleted, lead to a matrix $C$ of size $12\times 6$ that is full column rank $6$.

Can you suggest a formal way to do this? In particular, I would like to know if this is something we can understand from the row reduced echelon form of $A$.

---

**My thoughts:** By naive checking all possible pairs of columns of $A$, I have found that the "successful" pairs  are of the form $(i,j)$ where
$$
i\in \{1,4,5,6\}\\
j\in \{3,2,7,8\}\\
$$

In fact, take any $(i,j)$ where $i\in \{1,4,5,6\}$ and $j\in \{3,2,7,8\}$. Construct the matrix $C$ whose columns are the columns of matrix $A$ but the $i$-th and $j$-th columns. Then, $C$ has full column rank 6.

Note that, for example, the pair $(1,4)$ is not listed above. In fact, the matrix $C$ whose columns are the columns of matrix $A$ but the $1$-st and $4$-th columns has rank $5$.

I'm looking for a faster and more formal way to find all the "successful" pairs.

I thought about looking at the row reduced echelon form of $A$. This form suggests that we one "successful" pair is $(6,8)$. How can I find the others?

Comment: I haven't thought deeply about this but my intuition says that given the relatively small number of columns, brute force via computer would be a perfectly fine (and fast! maybe a few lines and microseconds in MATLAB) way to solve this problem, unless you are trying to generalize it. In which case the question might be, how do you want to generalize it; what more general phenomenon would produce the matrices of interest. I will think more carefully however.

Comment: Thanks. I want a "general" method if possible. My actual matrix is much bigger. This is a just a toy example.

Comment: I was wondering whether this something we can see from the row-reduced echelon form. For example (but, just wondering) looking at the columns with only a "1".